# How to use param value used as xpath in for-each for xslt

Tags: xslt, mule

I have a situation in xsl where I had a param value that will be assigned some     where in xslt transformation. But I get that param as a String , that param may contains a node a unbounded[0 or more repetitions] . How can I use param in for each as just any other xml content as used by any xpath expression.

Here is my sample xmls:
RetreiveData.xml

```
<soap-content>
------
<return>
<!--0 or more repetitions>-->
<data>
<startdate>12-12-12</startdate>
<enddate>12-12-13</enddate>
<nooftrans>5</nooftrans>
</data>
<data>
----
</data>

</soap=content>
```

This is my sample file which will be sent as param to xsl

xsl file:

```
<xsl style>
<param name ="retrieve"></param>
---
<xsl:for-each ="$retreive/return/data">
----do strufff
</xsl:for-each>


This was throwing an error . How can i travese to a node if it is param ?
```

I know this can be done using variable which is assigned to the path in a xml file . But that method is suggested in my scenario.

Can any one help me in solving this

Thanks in advance,
Eresh

Comment: Most likely, the error is due to your malformed `for-each` tag. You need to use the `select` attribute name: `xsl:for-each select="$retreive/return/data">` This tag is also malformed: `<xsl style>` and your `param` element is missing its namespace prefix.

Comment: Someone voted me down for mentioning the error in the code above (thanks, you rock) but still the error is there: the `param` is declared as "retrieve" and used as "retreive".

Comment: Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help If your posted code was well formed XSLT but guessing what you meant, then if $retrieve is a single element name you can do

```
<param name ="retrieve"></param>
---
<xsl:for-each select="*[name()=$retrieve]/return/data">
----do stuff
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that XPath variables hold values not fragments of expressions. If `$retrieve` held the string `"root"` then `$retrieve/return/data` is not `root/return/data/` it is `"root"/return/data` which is a syntax/type error as it is in most languages. If you have a string "x" in c or fortran, the expression  "x" + 1 does not add one to the *variable* x. To do that you need an XPath parser available at run time. Some products have extensions for that (and there is an evaluate function proposed for XPath 3) But for simple cases the above avoids the need to evaluate a string as an XPath.